# Using PSI Filter objects from Python

Tags: python, project-server, psi

I'm working with SharePoint and ProjectServer 2007 via PSI with Python.

I can't find any documentation on how [Filter Class (*Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Library*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.project.server.library.filter(v=office.12).aspx) objects work internally to emulate its behaviour in Python.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Colby Africa's blog post](http://colbyafrica.blogspot.com/2009/08/reading-lookup-table-structures-and.html). Also, [msdn docs are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453399(v=office.12).aspx).

**Edit**

The generated filter is just XML. Here is a filter that returns the data from the "LookupTables" table (list of all the lookup tables):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Filter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" filterTableName="LookupTables" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/ProjectServer/FilterSchema.xsd">
  <Fields>
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_UID" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_NAME" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_SORT_ORDER_ENUM" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_PRIMARY_LCID" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_FILL_ALL_LEVELS" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_CHECKOUTBY" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_CHECKOUTDATE" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="MOD_DATE" />
  </Fields>
  <Criteria />
</Filter>
```

Here is another example of the filters required for getting all the data for one table...

*Step 1: Get the row for the LookupTable (general table info)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Filter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" filterTableName="LookupTables" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/ProjectServer/FilterSchema.xsd">
  <Fields>
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_UID" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_NAME" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_SORT_ORDER_ENUM" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_PRIMARY_LCID" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_FILL_ALL_LEVELS" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_CHECKOUTBY" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_CHECKOUTDATE" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="MOD_DATE" />
  </Fields>
  <Criteria>
    <FieldOperator fieldOperationType="Equal">
      <Field fieldName="LT_UID" />
      <Operand xmlns:q1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xsi:type="q1:guid">20870732-12b6-48e2-acf4-94d934dfc27a</Operand>
    </FieldOperator>
  </Criteria>
</Filter>
```

*Step 2: Get all the data from the LookupTableStructures table (hierarchy info)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Filter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" filterTableName="LookupTableStructures" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/ProjectServer/FilterSchema.xsd">
  <Fields>
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_STRUCT_UID" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_UID" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_PARENT_STRUCT_UID" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_STRUCT_COOKIE" />
  </Fields>
  <Criteria>
    <FieldOperator fieldOperationType="Equal">
      <Field fieldName="LT_UID" />
      <Operand xmlns:q1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xsi:type="q1:guid">20870732-12b6-48e2-acf4-94d934dfc27a</Operand>
    </FieldOperator>
  </Criteria>
</Filter>
```

*Step 3: Get all of the values in this lookup table*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Filter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" filterTableName="LookupTableValues" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/ProjectServer/FilterSchema.xsd">
  <Fields>
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_STRUCT_UID" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LCID" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_UID" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_VALUE_DUR" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_VALUE_NUM" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_VALUE_DUR_FMT" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_VALUE_DATE" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_VALUE_TEXT" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_VALUE_PHONETIC" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_VALUE_FULL" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_VALUE_DESC" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_VALUE_SORT_INDEX" />
    <Field tableName="" fieldName="LT_VALUE_LOCALIZED_COOKIE" />
  </Fields>
  <Criteria>
    <FieldOperator fieldOperationType="Equal">
      <Field fieldName="LT_UID" />
      <Operand xmlns:q1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xsi:type="q1:guid">20870732-12b6-48e2-acf4-94d934dfc27a</Operand>
    </FieldOperator>
  </Criteria>
</Filter>
```

It requires three separate filters to get all this data because it is split across three separate tables. In C#, I am calling the `ReadLookupTablesMultiLang` function with each of these filters and then merging the returned datatables.

Comment: The problem here is that I don't have all these methods to build a Filter object (I am using Python). 

I think the best solution for me could be to see the syntax of the final XML sent in the HTTP request and generate something similar from Python.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the XML that is generated from an example when working with LookupTables. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Yeah! That's what I need! Now I'll try to generate the right query from Python. Thanks a lot!